# Ng-bootstrap modal window doesn't work in error part of subscription

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I have an angular app with login page. When I try to open error modal window after unsuccessful login I can see only faded background of modal, but he modal body is not shown. Although when I implement a `click` event on the other element with same functionality everything works as expected. Also, there are currently 2 modals on login page, second one is for successful registration and it works as expected. Here is HTML part of login component:

```
    <!-- start login error modal -->
    <ng-template #loginError let-modal>
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-basic-title">An error occured!</h4>
            <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="modal.dismiss('Cross click')">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div>Please, enter correct email and password.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="modal.close('Save click')">OK</button>
        </div>
    </ng-template>
    <!-- end login error modal -->

//everything works when you click on this element
<span class="footer-text" (click)="openError(loginError)">&nbsp;Policy</span>

//second modal window(works fine)
    <ng-template #content let-modal>
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-basic-title">Congratulations!</h4>
            <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="modal.dismiss('Cross click')">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div>You have successfully registered on our platform! Please log in using your username and password</div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="modal.close('Save click')">OK</button>
        </div>
    </ng-template>
```

TS component relevant part:

```
//onLogin function that shows just faded background when error occured
onLogin(loginError) {
  // activating submission flag
  this.submitted = true;

  // stop here if form is invalid
  if (this.loginForm.invalid) {
    return;
  }
  // activating loading flag
  this.loading = true;

  this.authenticationService.login(this.f.username.value, this.f.password.value)
    .pipe(first())
    // subscribing after successful login
    .subscribe(
      data => {
        //redirecting on "profile" page
        let id = data.id;
        this.router.navigate([`/user/${id}`]);
      },
      // error handling
      error => {
        this.loading = false;
        this.modalService.open(loginError);
      });
}

//function that works as expected
openError(loginError) {
  this.modalService.open(loginError)
}

//onRegister function that shows second modal as expected
onRegister(content) {
  // activating submission flag for register function
  this.submitReg = true;

  if (!this.registerForm.valid) {
    return
  }

  this.authenticationService
  // sending values to auth service function
    .signin(this.r.email.value, this.r.password.value, this.r.first_name.value, this.r.last_name.value, this.gender, `${this.year}-${this.month}-${this.day}`, true)
    .pipe(first())
    .subscribe(
      data => {
        this.submitReg = false;
        //open modal
        this.modalService.open(content);
        // reset register form
        this.registerForm.reset();
      },
      error => {
        this.loading = false;
      });
}
```

I tried to open second modal from onRegister function in onLogin but it didn't help either. Thank you for your help, any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Are both of the modal components registered as "entryComponents" in their module?

Comment: No, I've just put modals in ng-template, please advice how can I register them as entryComponent and why does second modal works and first modal works when span is clicked?

Comment: I don't know exactly, why only one of the above modals work. As far as I understood they are both in one Angular component, and I think this could mess up something. See my answer below for a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to create two separate Angular components for the two modals. When there are two components, they can be added to the wished module (most probably to the `app.module.ts`) as entry component at `entryComponents` array in the module decorator. The `entryComponents` are used for dynamically created components like the modal of ng-bootstrap.

You can find a good example code therefore here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-bootstrap-modals

And a tutorial for that here: https://medium.com/@izzatnadiri/how-to-pass-data-to-and-receive-from-ng-bootstrap-modals-916f2ad5d66e

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try